# [Pandas]The way to assign a new column based on if statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know assign could help to create/change one column based on lambda function like this:

```
df.assign(c = lambda x: x.sum())
```

But I couldn't find a way to do this with if-statement if I want to make the statement inline instead of doing it separately outside of the operation.

Is it possible to realize this without doing anything else outside of the operation:

```
df.assign(c = lambda x: x.num_col.sum() if x.num_col > 0)
```

The above command returns "**SyntaxError**: invalid syntax"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

**Data:**

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2),columns=list('ab'))

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
          a         b
0  0.493970  1.095644
1  0.128510 -0.542144
2  0.136247 -0.544499
3 -0.540835 -0.100574
4  0.052725 -0.164856
5 -1.201619  1.578153
6  1.921872  0.505875
7 -2.519725  0.282050
8 -1.581868 -0.240352
9 -0.071207 -1.366953

In [8]: df.iloc[:6]
Out[8]:
          a         b
0  0.493970  1.095644
1  0.128510 -0.542144
2  0.136247 -0.544499
3 -0.540835 -0.100574
4  0.052725 -0.164856
5 -1.201619  1.578153
6  1.921872  0.505875
```

let's find a sum of positive values in `a` column for the indexes: `[0:6]`:

```
In [9]: df.iloc[:6].query('a > 0').a.sum()
Out[9]: 2.733322288547374
```

**Solution:**

```
In [10]: df.iloc[:6].assign(c=lambda x: x.query('a > 0').a.sum())
Out[10]:
          a         b         c
0  0.493970  1.095644  2.733322
1  0.128510 -0.542144  2.733322
2  0.136247 -0.544499  2.733322
3 -0.540835 -0.100574  2.733322
4  0.052725 -0.164856  2.733322
5 -1.201619  1.578153  2.733322
6  1.921872  0.505875  2.733322
```

the same with renamed columns:

```
In [11]: df.iloc[:6].rename(columns={'a':'AAA', 'b':'BBB'}).assign(c=lambda x: x.query('AAA > 0').AAA.sum())
Out[11]:
        AAA       BBB         c
0  0.493970  1.095644  2.733322
1  0.128510 -0.542144  2.733322
2  0.136247 -0.544499  2.733322
3 -0.540835 -0.100574  2.733322
4  0.052725 -0.164856  2.733322
5 -1.201619  1.578153  2.733322
6  1.921872  0.505875  2.733322
```

---

**UPDATE:** starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

Comment: Thanks but df would be involved a number of operations already and this will have to separate the operation still.

Comment: @JingtaoYun, i didn't get it - what do you mean? Do you need a new __virtual__ column (using `assign` method) or a __permanent__ one?

Comment: a virtual one, because I want to a lot of operations behind df before doing assign such as df.ix[].rename()...assign().. So the df is not the original df to apply assign function.

Comment: This is perfectly working. Sorry wasn't making it more clear at the beginning. Thanks @MaxU

Answer (score -1):

The syntax is invalid because you're using the ternary condition, but only the first half.

The ternary condition allows you to write an `if` statement like this:

```
a = 1 if b > 0 else 0
```

In your case, you could write something like:

```
df = (
  df
  .assign(c = lambda x: x.num_col.sum() if x.num_col > 0 else 0)
)
```

Note the addition of the `else 0` at the end.

Comment: Did you try to run this code? I don't think it would actually work.

Comment: Thanks Michael for sharing this point of knowledge. But it doesn't work with error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().